# Variable keeps resetting

Tags: c, variables, global

I have written a piece of code that takes command line arguments to search txt files for a designated word, then returns the amount of times the word has been found. 
I'm trying to get it to only print the total count of the word found across all files, but at the moment I can only get it to print the amount of times the word has been found in each file individually.

an example of the code being run would be ./nameofcode birds test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt

I've tried a few different ideas but none of them seemed to work. The idea was to have the variable final count the total amount of times then print it after all the searches have been complete, but it justs resets after each search or stays at 0

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int final = 0;
  int result, errno;
  int i;
  int n;
  char * word = argv[1];
  char * list[200];
  //pid_t pid = fork();

  if (argc < 1) {
    exit(1);
  }
  system("cls");
  for (i = 2; i < argc; i = i + 1) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
      list[i] = argv[i];
      result = Search_in_File(word, list[i]);
      final = final + result;
      if (result == -1) {
        printf("\n Invalid input.");
      } else {
        printf("\n Total matches found: %d\n", result);
      }
      exit(0);
    }

    for (n = 0; n < argc - 1; n++) {
      wait(NULL);
    }

  }

  if (result == -1) {
    perror("Error");
    if (errno == 10) {
      printf("\n Invalid file");
      exit(1);
    } else {
      printf("\n Error number = %d\n", errno);
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("%d\n", final);

  }
  return (0);
}

int Search_in_File(char * str, char * fname) {
  FILE * fp;
  int line_num = 1;
  char temp[200];
  int find_result = 0;
  if ((fp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
    return (-1);
  }

  while (fgets(temp, 200, fp) != NULL) {

    if ((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL) {
      find_result++;
      //final++;    
    }
    line_num++;
  }

  if (find_result == 0) {
    printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
  }

  if (fp) {
    fclose(fp);
  }
  return (find_result);
}
```

if each file contained the word birds 3 times the expected result would be 9 but instead it is 3 or 0.

Comment: Why are you redefining `errno`? Will the compiler even allow that?

Comment: As for your problem, you're forgetting one very crucial bit about process and how `fork` works: The `fork` creates a new and *independent* process, the child process will run independently from the parent process, and most importantly will have its own separate virtual memory distinct from the parent process. Variables in the parent and child process will not be shared.

Comment: if you want to share variables between parent/child process, you need to have a shared memory region. not even `static` will help you there :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Using a local `errno` variable is _undefined behavior_. I'm not sure if it is undefined behavior if nothing includes `<errno.h>`, but it is definitely undefined behavior if `<errno.h>` has been included. (7.5p2). Regardless, the `if (errno == 10)` is _undefined behavior_ anyway as the local `errno` variable has not been intitialized or assigned to at that point.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm just thinking about that some implementations define `errno` as a macro that calls a function which returns a pointer which is dereferenced. On the other hand, depending on how the macro is defined it could be expanded to something which is a valid function forward declaration.

Comment: @IanAbbott Oh indeed, it’s explicitly defined as a macro. Odd, I checked a Linux man page instead there it said it was a *variable*.